# Required request part 'file' is not present- Java Spring and Angular 7

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a problem with the `POST` method in Angular 6. I want to send an image to the server, I tried from the Postman and my Spring boot work pretty good and my image is saved on the server but when I sent from the Angular project I have the error:

> 2019-02-18 10:40:07.086  WARN 6496 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
>   [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException:
>   Required request part 'file' is not present]

This is my template:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileSelectedMethod($event)">
<button (click)="onUploadButton()">Upload!</button>
```

This is my component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

 selectedFinenew: File = null;
 constructor(private data: DataServiceService, private http: HttpClient) { }
  ngOnInit() {}
 onFileSelectedMethod(event) {
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
  }

  onUploadButton() {
    const fb = new FormData();
    fb.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.http.post('api/cateogry/dar/uploadFile', fb).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    }
    );
  }
```

My method in Spring Boot:

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFile")
        public UploadFileResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
            String fileName = fileStorageService.storeFile(file);

            String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                    .path("/downloadFile/")
                    .path(fileName)
                    .toUriString();

            return new UploadFileResponse(fileName, fileDownloadUri,
                    file.getContentType(), file.getSize());
        }
```

Comment: Can you share your `Controller` code from Java?

Comment: Yes, now you can see.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `file` within your `formData`.

You should change

`fb.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);`

to

`fb.append('file', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);`

or

Change

`@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file`

to

`@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file`